# How do I convert TSX to JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a project where I wrote some new code in Expo with TypeScript (since I am more used to having a type safe language).  However, I want to port what I wrote to something that was written with Expo with JavaScript.

I can manually just strip off the types as I go along to solve the problem, but I was wondering if there's a more automatic way of doing it.  I know typescript eventually compiles down to JavaScript but I want to keep the HTML embedded code the same when I do the conversion.  Is it possible?

Comment: Just run `tsc`?

Comment: If just running `tsc` doesn't work, read this https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/typescript/typescript-compiling

Effectively you can just compile it into Javascript.

Comment: If the output of `tsc` is too much, just go through the `tsx` files and remove TS specific syntax, then rename to .jsx.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The answer provided by @Jason is close to what I needed.

In the end I ran this command

```
npx tsc --jsx preserve -t es2020 --outDir js --noEmit false
```

This generated the `.js` and `.jsx` files in the `js` folder which can be copied over to non-typescript systems.

`--noEmit false` is needed for the Expo generated tsconfig.js which is `noEmit: true`

The `-t es2020` generates output using ES2020 standards so you can get `import` and `export` along with the `async` `await` intact.

Comment: I was able to convert tsx files to jsx, but it did not carry the scss files.

Answer (score 3):

In the tsconfig.json file change `"jsx": "react"` to `"jsx": "preserve"` and then run tsc.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsx.html